# While fetching async data, notify block gets called early, before getting the required results.Want to reload collectionView after all data fetched

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Called the below method in viewDidLoad() and used Firestore cache to get the data then append to an array. After getting the whole response I want to reload my collectionView(which I am doing through notify block). Please let me know where am I wrong, here is my code:

```
  func getArchivedTasks(completion: @escaping ([ArchivedTasksModel],Bool) -> ()) {

    var archTasks : [ArchivedTasksModel] = []
    let viewModels = self.fetchTaskCardsFromDB()
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    for newItem in viewModels {

        let newTask = ArchivedTasksModel()
        newTask.taskCard = newItem

        firestoreManager.getLastComment(taskId: newTask.taskCard?.id ?? "") { (commnt, res) in
            group.enter()
            newTask.comment = commnt
            archTasks.append(newTask)
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(archTasks, true)
    }
}
```

Comment: check whether all the responses are successful? Have you considered a possibility where a certain call fails? Check for fail case and call group.leave() for the same. The notify would not be called even if a single group is yet to leave.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I checked for a fail case and added the same and in my getLastComment() method and the notify did get called.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `enter` the group **before** calling the asynchronous task

```
group.enter()
firestoreManager.getLastComment(taskId: newTask.taskCard?.id ?? "") { (commnt, res) in ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it, and then, notify block does not execute.

Comment: It should work, that's the standard syntax. Is the code in the closure executed?

Comment: Code is not executed at any point. I have debugged and checked

Comment: Then the issue (*notify block does not execute*) is related to the task itself.